# Mocha not print result in console after api hit

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Here is my mocha script. I am hitting an api and in that api, i will send the result. I need to print the results obtained. While i print it, it is always saying as undefined. How can i do this.

```
var assert = require('assert');
console.log('Starting Test...')
describe('api', function() {
  describe('GET /getStore', function(data) {
    it('respond with an array of users', function() {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: check your server GET route if it responds with a value.

Comment: It renders a page, is that an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Use http.get to get the api results..

```js
var server = require ('./server'),
    assert = require ('assert'),
    http = require ('http');
var port = 8085;

describe('server', function () {
    before(function () {
        server.listen(port);
    });

    after(function () {
        server.close();
    });

    describe('Server status and Message', function () {
      it('status response should be equal 200', function (done) {
            http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8085', function (response) {
                  assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
                  done();
            });
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: my index.js file is in the root  of the folder.